# How to set variable alpha and beta for cv2.addWeighted?

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to see how two images combine over a range of weight values. I'm using the Python code below, but the `cv2.addWeighted` doesn't take as `alpha` and `beta` the `i/30` and `1-i/30` values in the for loop. Could someone please tell me how to fix that?

```
import cv2

# read two images
src1 = cv2.imread('image1.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
src2 = cv2.imread('image2.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# add or blend the images
for i in range (1,30):

  dst = cv2.addWeighted(src1, i/30, src2,  1-i/30, 0.0)

  # save the output image
  cv2.imwrite('newfolder\\image'+str(i)+'.png', dst)
```

Comment: Can you please further elaborate on the actual error you get? I can run your code as is (after adapting the destination path), and the results seem reasonable. Make sure, that `newfolder` exists, before running the script. Also, instead of saving all the images: There's a [nice tutorial on OpenCV's trackbar](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html) for exact that use case!

Comment: @HansHirse If OP is using Python 2, then `i/30` is integer division... so the weights are always 0 and 1.

Comment: @DanMašek Aah, of course - you're right! I always forget about that, especially since it's not reflected in the question and/or tags. So, `float(i)/30` should do the trick, I guess.

Comment: @DanMašek Great, you solved the case! Thank you very much Hans too!

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Mašek's comment says, you should cast `i` to float to avoid implicit integer division in Python 2 which will always leave your alpha and beta as 1 or 0.

```py
dst = cv2.addWeighted(src1, float(i)/30, src2,  1-float(i)/30, 0.0)
```